# Video streaming from java to android

Tags: java, video-streaming, android-videoview, encode, jcodec

I'm using JCodec + webcam-capture (https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture).
I would get images from webcam and send directly (after encoding) to android.
The problem is that if I send the images just encoding, the VideoView in android give errors.
If I use SequenceEncoder (from JCodec) and use the method .finish (I'm creating a file) when I send it the VideoView works well.
How can I resolve?
Another solution I tried is create a lot of small files and send to Android. It works but is too slow.